# In The Others, can you teleport a monster out of an area with a hero in it?

Tags: untagged

In The Others, we've got two conflicting rules here, so I'm curious which one takes precedence.

On the one hand, under "Spaces With Heroes" it says:

> The Sins Player cannot Move a monster out of a Hero-occupied Space
>   for any reason

On the other hand, under Teleport it says:

> If a card or ability allows a figure to be teleported to a
>   different Space, all Movement-related rules are ignored.

So... when the Sins-player is teleporting a Monster, does this cancel the above rule, which explicitly says "for any reason", or did Teleport really mean to say "ignore all Movement-related rules except the one that explicitly says it can't be subverted for any reason"?

Since both rules are quite absolute, I'm not sure what the correct ruling should be here.

Comment: I suspect you'll find that Teleport and Move are two different actions, which is why movement restrictions don't apply to Teleport.

Comment: @ikegami can you back that up with anything? That'd solve my issue :)

Comment: Read the phrasing; it wasn't an answer, but a possible answer. It's just something for you to consider because the choice of same-or-different verb is often very important in board games. I can't do more right now.

Comment: Actually, you didn't even include what Teleport does, so I have no idea what verb is used, so what I said might not apply at all.

Comment: Ok, it does appear to use the word "Teleport", and other players reached the [same conclusion](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1619393/teleport) as I did